# Matlab will not run my C++ .exe file

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, matlab, cmd

I have program in C++ that runs great but it has different steps in it. It opens a file first then does some calculations based on the data it gets from the file. Now I'm trying to run it through matlab. I tried mex but it got too complicated because I have VS 2010 Express and MATLAB 2007b. And so mex can never find my c compiler.

I'm now trying to just run it straight from the C++ program executable file. Here's how I tried to do it:

```
system('C:\path\file.exe')
```

it would run but the command window freezes and I have to close Matlab every time to get back on track. Then I tried to double click on the executable file it self. It flashes but I can see it outputs something from my file `"file could not be uploaded"` which is generated by a part of my program if it cant find the file.

So then I realized it's probably because of that that caused it to not run and crash.
So I wrote a sample code to open the file first before the system command open the `.exe` file. I've done something like `fopen('fname','r')`, but nothing works. Please note that this file I'm trying to open is a `.COF` file.

I tried running the `.exe` file using debug and release modes but nothing happens. It gives no errors which means it sees the `.exe` file but the command line doesn't come up and matland command window freezes.

After running, it's supposed to prompt the user at the command line then take input arguments and output something...

Please help....

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing that your .COF file is in a different path than what's accessible by your binary. If you can recompile, try an absolute path name, and test it first without MATLAB.

There are more thorough ways to solve this, like passing the filename to your binary as a command line argument, or to read up what the rules are for the "current directory" when you use `system`, but perhaps you'd be happy with the quick solution.

Comment: What do you mean by absolute path?
And as of right now I'd any possible way. I also copied my .COF file in the same File.m directory I'm running and did not help me

Comment: What do you mean by absolute path?
And as of right now I'd try any possible way to have it running I also copied my .COF file in the same File.m directory I'm running and did not help me

Comment: Thanks for your input. The executable file works now. But Matlab still can run it.  The window command stays into the running mode and nothing come up

Comment: Anybody else care to comment. Because When I run system('C:\path\path\.exe ')

Comment: Anybody else care to comment. Because When I run system('C:\path\path\.exe ') in the command window it just stays in debugging mode and nothing comes up. I have literally restart matlab everytime. the .exe file and the .COF is in the same directory